# Show if $A^r = I$ for some positive $r \in \mathbb{Z^+},$ and $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $\alpha^r = 1.$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square matrix of complex numbers such that $A^r = I$ for some positive integer $r.$  If $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of A, show that $\alpha^r = 1.$  This problem is out of chapter 10.1 in Lang's 3rd Ed. Linear Algebra, a section discussing what he calls "triangulation of matrices and  linear maps".

This problem is easy if $A$ is guaranteed diagonalizable, because if $A = S\Lambda S^{-1},$ then $S\Lambda^r S^{-1} = I,$ and from here its clear that $\alpha^r = 1.$  However, the problem does not say anything about diagonalizable.

So my question is twofold, 1) is there a way to do this without assuming $A$ diagonalizable? and 2) Can we conclude that $A$ is diagonalizable somehow from the fact that $A^r = I$ for some positive integer $r?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then, for $v\not=0$,

$Av=\lambda v\implies A^rv=\lambda^rv\implies Iv=\lambda^r v\implies \lambda^rv=v\implies\lambda^r=1$

Comment: Well thats a whole lot easier than what I was trying! Thanks